# How to find the time difference between first row and the row when the condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find the time difference (in minutes) between the beginning and the moment when `col1` exceeds the value `20`.

For the data below, the answer should be 72 minutes (from 20:00:19 till 21:12:00).

`df`:

```
date_time            col1
2018-03-04 20:00:19  9
2018-03-04 21:10:00  13
2018-03-04 21:12:00  21
2018-03-04 21:15:00  25
```

How can I do it?
This is my current snippet:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])
start = df.index[0]
row_id = df.index[df['col1'] > 20]
time_val = start - df.index[row_id]
```

Comment: can you print your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After transforming your columns to the desired output:

```
df.date_time=pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
df.col1=pd.to_numeric(df.col1)
id=df[df.col1>20].col1.idxmin()
diff=(df.iloc[id].date_time-df.iloc[0].date_time).seconds/60
```

Comment: I selected your answer, because a detailed solution for me is more preferable than a single line solution.

Comment: Thanks @Tatik, yes, sometimes is better to be able to understand the answer !

Answer (score 4):

One liner:

```
ans = pd.to_datetime(df.groupby(df.col1>20).first().date_time).diff().dt.total_seconds()/60
```

#### output:

```
ans[True]:

71.68333333333334
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution, Yuca. Though I selected another solution, because sinlge line approach is less preferable for my case (worse readability).

Comment: wise choice, happy coding

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `'date_time'` is dtype datetime.  We can use `diff` to get `Timedelta` and `cumsum` to get cumulative `Timedelta`.  Then we can use `idxmax` on `df.col1.gt(20)`

```
df.date_time.diff().fillna(0).cumsum()[df.col1.gt(20).idxmax()]

Timedelta('0 days 01:11:41')
```

`Timedelta` has a `total_seconds` method that you can divide by `60`

```
df.date_time.diff().fillna(0).cumsum()[df.col1.gt(20).idxmax()].total_seconds() / 60

71.68333333333334
```

Or you can divide by another `Timedelta`

```
df.date_time.diff().fillna(0).cumsum()[df.col1.gt(20).idxmax()] / pd.Timedelta(1, unit='m')

71.68333333333334
```

Comment: genuine question, why `idxmax()`? wouldn't that return the largest stamp that's larger than 20? (vs returning the smallest, which is what we want)

Comment: @Yuca `idxmax` returns the *first* occurence of a maximum, which in a boolean array is the first `True`

Comment: this approach breaks my brain, this is very cool, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

IIUC I am using `ptp`

```
df.loc[df.col1.le(20).shift().cumprod().ne(0),'date_time'].ptp()
Out[1232]: Timedelta('0 days 01:11:41')
```

Comment: @ALollz just short version of max - min :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['col'] > 20:
        total_seconds = int((df1['date_time'][0] - row['date_time']).total_seconds())
        minutes, remainder = divmod(total_seconds,60)
        print('{} mins'.format(minutes))
        break
```